# ubuntu 16.04 install on compaq 311 with atom n270 cpu gives 'wrong image' error

Tags: 16.04, system-installation, atom

i'm using the image:
ubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-i386.iso

following advise on this forum, i looked int he bios to enable the VT setting. didn't find it in my bios.
also looked for guest settings to change 'type' and 'version' to 'other'.
didn't find those setting either.
bios insyde vf.12 rev 3.4

any suggestions?

tnx,
ams

Answer (score 1):

The Atom N270 doesn't support virtualization/VT-x.

[Source](http://ark.intel.com/products/36331/Intel-Atom-Processor-N270-512K-Cache-1_60-GHz-533-MHz-FSB)

Therefore, you can't run VMs on your machine.

However, you do not need virtualization to install Ubuntu. Follow the instructions here: [How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Comment: thanks 4 the rapid response pat.  i know the notebook w/ the atom n270 doesn't support virtualization. this shouldn't rule out running 16.04 though. i'm interested in running it native, not under any sort of hypervisor. any suggestions? -tnx.

Comment: @arthurshermanavrahamshir-el Haha, the forum you visited was trying to tell you how to install Ubuntu in VirtualBox. If you want to install it natively see http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu. You don't need virtualization for installing Ubuntu natively. If this answer helped mark it as correct :)